# String.hashCode same value for different sequences

Tags: dart

What could the problem be?  I expect different value of s1.hashCode ad s2.hashCode, but they are the same.

dart --version // Dart VM version: 1.21.1 (Fri Jan 13 09:44:01 2017) on "linux_x64"

```
main() {
  String s1 = "x-14-9";
  String s2 = "f-107";
  print(s1.hashCode);   // 939886624
  print(s2.hashCode);   // 939886624
  print("identical - ${identical(s1,s2)}");   // identical - false
  print("== - ${s1 == s2}");                  // == - false
}
```

When I try this code in DartPad - everything is going well, values different.

Comment: "I expect different value of s1.hashCode ad s2.hashCode" - hash codes don't actually promise that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many real programs, [perfect hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) do not exist.

That means that different objects may potentially *collide* (i.e. have the same `hashCode`, in Dart). Most implementations of things like a `HashMap` fall back on using an equality check on collisions.

You don't have to worry about this when using the standard library:

```
var map = new Map<String, int>();
map['x-14-9'] = 1;
map['f-107'] = 2;
print(map); // Should print both key-value pairs.
```

Comment: Indeed, as an extreme, your programs should still *work* (albeit inefficiently) if the `.hashCode` of *every* object of a particular class were all a constant 42.